# listing all intermediate recurrence results

Tags: c++, recursion, functional-programming, c++20, recurrence

I have a function

```
int f(int);
```

I want to get

```
[0, f(0), f(f(0)), f(f(f(0))), ...]
```

until f return -1.
I was wondering if there is a name for this in functional programming. It looks like recursion.

Comment: What is e.g. `(f|f)(0)` supposed to mean? That you call `f(0)` twice? That it's the second call to `f(0)`? If you're supposed to call `f(0)` twice, how are you supposed to combine the results?

Comment: And what is the actual and underlying problem you're supposed to solve? Why do you think something like you propose would solve that problem? Please elaborate on the question and the actual problem.

Comment: `f(f(0))` isn't recursion. It's really the same as `int res1 = f(0); int res2 = f(res1);` Hopefully that should also give you a broad idea about how to possibly solve it, if you put it in a loop and append to a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: that's one way to do it. I was wondering if there would be a more functional way. Maybe there isn't.

Comment: The term for this is "iteration".  @Someprogrammerdude 's comment shows how to do it.

Comment: Considering the C++20 tag (which I briefly removed for the generic C++ tag) then perhaps [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) could be helpful? Or the original [ranges library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) if your compiler doesn't fully support `std::ranges` yet.

Comment: I'd be very curious about how to do this with ranges. Been thinking about it but still can't find how.

Comment: I'd expect that functionality provided by a range factory, and see none applicable even in C++23. But I'm far to be an expert about range, my expectations may be badly informed.

Comment: You can use views::iota() as an infinite number generator, which could be a starting point, and then using take_while() you can break the generation on some condition. I don't know how to access the predecessor in the range.

Comment: Maybe in math.stackexchange.com someone knows if this kind of vector has a formal name.

Comment: As you are in the process of generating the range, you need to access the previous item in the range. I don't know how it can be done.

Comment: @pptaszni It's called a *recurrence*. The operation producing it is called a *recurrence relation*.

Comment: As for how to compute it without a manual loop, check out [`std::partial_sum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum).

Comment: A recursive definition would yield a tree structure (completely unbalanced though): `[x [f(x), [f(f(x)), [...]]]`. In a strictly evaluated language you'd need eta expansion to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `f(f(0))` is the function call stack that emerges using recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing in range-v3 to do this `views::partial_sum`<sup>1</sup>. This takes a *binary* function, applying it to the result of the previous element in the destination range and the next element in the source range.

But here, we can simply ignore the next element in the source range, since we don't care about it - just the previous element:

```cpp
auto recurrence =
    rv::iota(0)
    | rv::partial_sum([](int prev, int){
        return f(prev);
      })
    | rv::take_while([](int i){
        return i != -1;
      })
```

`iota(0)` gives you the range `[0, 1, 2, ...]`. It doesn't actually matter what the contents are after the `0`, just that they're infinite. `rv::repeat(0)` also works, that's just the range `[0, 0, 0, ...]`

The `partial_sum` then gives you the range `[0, f(0), f(f(0)), f(f(f(0))), ...]`

And then `take_while` stops when we reach `-1`. Note that `-1` is *not* included in the result - if you want to include that, the construction is... trickier.

In general though, this kind of thing is much easier to do with a generator:

```cpp
auto recurrence() -> generator<int> {
    int i = 0;
    while (i != -1) {
        co_yield i;
        i = f(i);
    }
}
```

Which is also easier to restructure if you want to include the `-1`:

```cpp
auto recurrence() -> generator<int> {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        co_yield i;
        if (i == -1) {
            break;
        }
        i = f(i);
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> range-v3 has `views::generate`, but that takes a nullary function - it gives you the range `[f(), f(), f(), ...]`, but allowing for `f()` to return a different value every time. I suppose we could use that to do:

```cpp
views::generate([cur=0, next=0]() mutable {
    cur = next;
    next = f(next);
    return cur;
})
```

Which we could built up a:

```cpp
auto generate_unary = [](auto init, auto f){
    return views::generate([cur=init, next=init, f]() mutable {
        cur = next;
        next = f(next);
        return cur;
    });
};
```

And then we can `generate_unary(0, f)`

Comment: partial_sum() is a strange name. Does it have something to do with fold() which I have seen showing up in the C++23 listing ?

Comment: @LudovicAubert The problem is that it simply preferences `+` as the operation. If you do a `partial_sum` with an op other than `+`, it looks silly. Same with `accumulate` doing something more complicated (which is why I called it `ranges::fold` and not `ranges::accumulate`). `partial_sum` is a special case of `scan` - and `scan` and `fold` are closely related: `fold` just gives you the final value while `scan` gives you all the values along the way.